# Why tuneRF does not have a good result for ctree in R

Tags: r, optimization, random-forest

I tried to use `tuneRF` for selecting the minimal `OOB` value for best `mtry` value in `ctree` model. However, if I use the right value I get worse results than just increasing the `mtry` value.
Here is my code:

```
library(party)
dat1 <- fread('https://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/machine-learning-databases/abalone/abalone.data',stringsAsFactors=T)

## split data to train and test
set.seed(123)
dat1 <- subset(dat1, !is.na(V1))
smp_size<-100
train_ind <- sample(seq_len(nrow(dat1)), size = smp_size)
train <- dat1[train_ind, ]
test <- dat1[-train_ind, ]

ct <- ctree(V1 ~ ., data = train)

test$CTVAL<- predict(ct, test[,V2:V9])
> mean (test$V1==test$CTVAL)
0.5020849
```

Now I run `tuneRF`:

```
> bestmtry <- tuneRF(train[, V2:V9], train$V1, stepFactor = 1.5, improve = 1e-5, ntree = 500)
mtry = 2  OOB error = 47% 
Searching left ...
Searching right ...
mtry = 3    OOB error = 52% 
-0.106383 1e-05
```

It recommends `mtry =2`.
Running same model with `mtry = 2` (replace the line `ct<-...`):

```
ct <- ctree(V1 ~ ., data = train,controls = ctree_control(mtry = 2 ))


 > mean (test$V1==test$CTVAL)
0.4841795
```

And using the same model with `mtry = 10`:

```
 ct <- ctree(V1 ~ ., data = train,controls = ctree_control(mtry = 10 ))


     > mean (test$V1==test$CTVAL)
0.5109149
```

Comment: Auto-tuning is often times nice, but you have to keep in my mind that is is just a quick and dirty step that can be very off sometimes (for ex. if you have junk data or a lot of noise), in that case you have to adjust it manually.